# ¿Cómo puedo crear un botón de HTML con la etiqueta <a> que lleve a otra sección de la misma página?

Tags: html

Estoy creando una página web donde tengo el siguiente codigo para crear un botón:

```
<a href="" target="_blank">Contacto</a>
```

Me gustaría que el botón llevara a una parte posterior de la página ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

*Si conocen una forma más sencilla de crear un botón y me la dicen también estaré muy agradecido.*

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es sencillo:

coloca tu a tu div un id

```
<div id="panel">
    Hola
</div>
```

y en el a colocas

```
<a href="#panel" >Contacto</a>
```

y te enviará a esa parte de la página.

Comment: Me funcionó, gracias

Comment: Recuerda que si deseas enviarlo a una url sin dar click en nigún boton solo colcas el # en la url por ejemplo url.com#panel y de una te enviara alli

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una alternativa con efecto de desplazamiento suave usando CSS.

Para crear un efecto suave solo tendrías que añadir `scroll-behavior: smooth;` al elemento `HTML`, esto te permite un desplazamiento suave de toda la página.

```
html {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

> **Nota**: también es posible agregarlo a un elemento / contenedor de desplazamiento específico.

Para dirigirte a un contenido en específico simplemente le pases el valor del atributo *id* al enlace, algo como `<a href="#contacto">Contacto</a>` y la caja del contenido seria `<section id='contacto'></section>`

**Posible ejemplo:**

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
a {
 color: white;
}
a:hover {
 color: #CCCCCC;
}
#red,
#blue {
  background-color:red;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 250px;
  padding:50px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
#blue {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="red">
  <h1>Inicio</h1>
  <a href="#blue">Contacto</a>
</div>

<div id='blue'>
  <h1>Contacto</h1>
  <a href="#red">Inicio</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar un anclaje, debes poner un id al elemento donde quieres que se posicione, ejemplo el header, y en el href pones #iddelelemento Ej:
 Ir a Titulo

Comment: Perfecto, gracias